# Overriding non-parameterized classes nested in a parameterized outer class in Java

Tags: java

Can someone please help with the syntax of subclassing a non-parameterized nested class inside a parameterized outer class, like the following?

```
public abstract class Foo<T> {

    public class Bar {
        Set<T> aSet;
    }

    abstract class Baz {
        abstract void doSomething(Map<? extends Bar, T> aMap);
    } 
}
```

Then in a separate file, I'm not entirely sure how to define the type variable `S` here without parameterizing `ConcreteBaz`. And I can't use a wildcard variable like `extends Foo<?>.Baz` (I think) because I need access to that generic type variable in the `doSomething` method:

```
public class ConcreteBaz extends Foo<S>.Baz {    // compilation error

    public ConcreteBaz(Foo<S> foo) { foo.super(); }

    public void doSomething(Map<? extends Foo<S>.Bar, S> aMap) { ... }

}
```

Can someone please help me figure out a way around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Your problem is that the nested class is nonstatic. I'll check it out, but I'm pretty sure you cannot subclass such classes, except maybe if nested in the same class, or when creating an anonymous type.</del>

<del>Is declaring the nested class static viable? Them it would definitely work.</del>

Edit: scratch all that. I don't have a compilation error. What is `S` in your case? You do realize you have to pass a concrete class to Foo, and cannot leave it parametrized with an unknown parameter S?

Answer (score 0):

If `ConcreteBaz` needs to refer to the type parameter, that implies that it needs the type parameter itself:

```
public class ConcreteBaz<S> extends Foo<S>.Baz {
```

Comment: You can supply an instance for the enclosing `Foo` to the constructor, see my example (I've tried it in an IDE).

Comment: @Jesper: Whoops, thanks. I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @lrfy: Yes, but apparently I didn't try it in quite the right way! :-P

Comment: Understood. It seemed to me that since the type variable `T` is visible to `Foo<T>.Baz`, then it should also be visible to subclasses of `Foo<T>.Baz`. I guess that generic type variables don't get inherited the same way that other instance variables do.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `S` as a type parameter:

```
public class ConcreteBaz<S> extends Foo<S>.Baz {
```

Otherwise the compiler will think `S` is a concrete type instead of a type parameter.

Complete example:

```
public class ConcreteBaz<S> extends Foo<S>.Baz {
    public ConcreteBaz(Foo<S> foo) {
        foo.super();
    }

    @Override
    void doSomething(Map<? extends Foo<S>.Bar, S> aMap) {
        // ...
    }
}
```